# CSS - animate parent when child element of variable height expands

Tags: html, css, animation

I have some HTML like:

```
<div class="parent">
  Some initial content...
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

The content in the `.child` div gets populated via an ajax call and is of variable height. I animate the expansion of the child via:

```
.child {
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform 500ms ease-out;
  transform-origin: top left;
}

/* add this class dynamically to the child */
.child-dynamic {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

My question: is there a performant way (ie. css only) to animate the parent container expanding as needed to accommodate the expanding `child`? Right now the parent height increases and decreases instantly.

Thanks!

Comment: No. You would have to animate the height of the new child to do that.

Comment: Transform is purely visual, it does not actually change the dimensions of the element.

Comment: thanks, much I get it now.